# Linux ext4 restore file and directory access rights after bad backup/restore

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I kind of screwed up the backup of my personal directory with `rsync` (maybe because I'm backuping on an NTFS filesystem): all files are here but all files and directories access rights are 777. I was wondering if there was a *magic* utility that would recursively change:

- the directories from 777 to 755.
- the regular files from 777 to 644. I don't have many executables in my home, so I can manage that by hand later.
- leave other files (links, any thing else ?) unchanged.

Doing it in shell is easy, but it will take hours...

Subsidiary question: any advice to backup properly a linux directory hierarchy on NTFS (with `rsync`or other).

Comment: How big is that directory? Why would it take hours from the shell? The magic utilities you are asking for are exactly in the shell..

Comment: What is a Linux hierarchy? Are you talking about WSL? If so, note that there's a lot more metadata than just the file permissions that you might need to worry about, especially if the directory is on LXFS rather than DrvFS. Including stuff like per-directory case sensitivity.

Comment: "Subsidiary question: any advice to backup properly a linux directory hierarchy on NTFS (with rsyncor other)." – You should ask your question as a question, but the short answer on how to backup properly a linux directory hierarchy on NTFS is to not backup a linux directory hierarchy on NTFS. NTFS is designed for Windows, and while it *technically* does support (most if not all of) the metadata required to back up Linux files, a simple copy or `rsync` will not use the special APIs required to maintain those. Use `pax`, that's what it's for.

Comment: For archival purposes use "tar" to pack up a directory.  This will not give you rsync update speeds but will maintain all unix attributes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard recommended solution is straight-forward:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 "{}" \+
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 "{}" \+
```

This will append as many filenames as possible as arguments to a single command,
up to the system's maximum command line length. If the line exceeds this length,
the command will be called multiple times.

If you want to call the command once per file, you can instead do:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 "{}" \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 "{}" \;
```

Comment: Actually, I see that [@Fanatique's way](https://superuser.com/a/1462066/83694) is faster because it involves fewer calls to `chmod` thanks to argument appending.  Your answer can be improved by changing `\;` to `\+`, which will also enable argument appending.

Comment: @Deltik: I saw your edit, but was in the process of doing mine.

Comment: The `\;` way is so slow that my benchmark of it has been running for over 5 minutes compared to [about 14 seconds with `\+`](https://superuser.com/a/1462081/83694).  I would recommend removing `\;` from your answer.

Comment: @Deltik: The added quoting in this case changes absolutely nothing. In both cases, `find` receives the same parameters `[..., "-exec", "chmod", "0755", "{}", ";"]` as argv. In both cases, when it finds a parameter that's exactly `"{}"` it is replaced with the file name still as one parameter. The only time it would actually make a difference is if you had `-exec sh -c "chmod 0755 {}" \;` i.e. if it was a substring replacement.

Comment: @Deltik: I still want the answer to be comprehensive, but I made it clear that this is the preferred method for many files.

Comment: @grawity: You're right; that's my bad.

Comment: `+` is not a shell special; there's no need to escape it.

Answer (score 16):

`chmod -R a=,u+rwX,go+rX $DIR` seems to work fine, and is very likely to be the fastest, however you look at it.

(I checked with `strace`, and it makes only *one* `fchmodat()` syscall per file/directory -- for files that is with 644 and for directories with 755).

The trick is the `X` permmission, documented in `man chmod`, which acts like `x` for directories only -- the very distinction you wanted.

What is *not* documented is my guess that they would be applied in the same sequence as they are specified, and not just in some random order, but repeated tests with several variants have convinced me that they do indeed run in the order given, so I am pretty sure this is always going to work like this.

I should mention this is on Linux, though a cursory reading of the BSD manpage for chmod suggest that it *should* work there also.

Comment: This way is indeed the fastest, as shown in [my answer with updated benchmarks](https://superuser.com/a/1462081/83694).

Comment: Update: I found a [≈40% faster method](https://superuser.com/a/1462081/83694) that makes use of task parallelism!

Comment: about the parallelism: is this on an SSD or some very fast disk?  Does the benchmark tool run a `sync` afterward to ensure everything is written out to disk?

Comment: I ran [the tests](https://pastebin.com/raw/mXUV1A82) on a NVMe SSD in [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1462081/83694), but I was able to get similar results on two machines ([1](https://pastebin.com/raw/TgDRpRne), [2](https://pastebin.com/raw/NTtBCErR)) with HDDs. `sync` didn't seem to make a difference. I did not run the tests on just one plain hard drive, though, because I don't have any machines with just a hard drive at the moment.  ([More info](https://superuser.com/questions/1462062/1462092#comment2206022_1462081))

Answer (score 10):

I benchmarked [sitaram's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1462092/83694), [Peter Cordes's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1462062/linux-ext4-restore-file-and-directory-access-rights-after-bad-backup-restore/1462081#comment2205143_1462081), [Fanatique's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1462066/83694), and [harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1462065/83694), but **this answer has the fastest way**.

Averages:

- Deltik's answer* – 7.480 seconds

  <sup><sub>* Credit to [Peter Cordes](https://superuser.com/users/20798/peter-cordes) for [suggesting parallelism](https://superuser.com/questions/1462062/linux-ext4-restore-file-and-directory-access-rights-after-bad-backup-restore/1462081#comment2205489_1462081)</sub></sup>
- sitaram's answer – 12.962 seconds (73.275% slower than best)
- Peter Cordes's comment – 14.414 seconds (92.685% slower than best)
- Fanatique's answer – 14.570 seconds (94.772% slower than best)
- harrymc's updated answer – 14.791 seconds (97.730% slower than best)
- harrymc's original answer – 1061.926 seconds (14096.113% slower than best)

Full statistical summary:

```
Author              N      min     q1      median  q3      max     mean    stddev
------------------  --     ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- --------
Deltik              10     7.121   7.3585  7.4615  7.558   8.005   7.4804  0.248965
sitaram             10     12.651  12.803  12.943  13.0685 13.586  12.9617 0.276589
Peter Cordes        10     14.096  14.2875 14.375  14.4495 15.101  14.4136 0.269732
Fanatique           10     14.219  14.512  14.5615 14.6525 14.892  14.5697 0.211788
harrymc (updated)   10     14.38   14.677  14.8595 14.9025 15.119  14.791  0.21817
harrymc (original)  1      1061.93 1061.93 1061.93 1061.93 1061.93 1061.93 N/A
```

**Deltik's command, in benchmark format:**

```
find "$(pwd)" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -P4 chmod 755 & \
find "$(pwd)" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P4 chmod 644 & wait
```

sitaram's command, in benchmark format:

```
chmod -R a=,u+rwX,go+rX "$(pwd)"
```

Peter Cordes's command, in benchmark format:

```
find "$(pwd)" \( -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + \) \
           -o \( -type f -exec chmod 644 {} + \)
```

Fanatique's command, in benchmark format:

```
find "$(pwd)" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755 ; \
find "$(pwd)" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

harrymc's updated command, in benchmark format:

```
find "$(pwd)" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + ; \
find "$(pwd)" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

harrymc's original command, in benchmark format:

```
find "$(pwd)" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; ; \
find "$(pwd)" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

My command was the fastest thanks to the four parallel `chmod` processes per file type.  This allowed multiple CPU cores to run `chmod`, which moves the bottleneck towards kernel I/O threads or the disk.

sitaram's command was the runner-up because everything is done within the `chmod` command.  This substantially reduces overhead compared to the other answers because:

- The files only need to be scanned once (similar to doing one `find` instead of two), and
- No child processes need to be created.

This command is the least flexible, however, because it relies on a trick involving the differing meaning of the executable bit between regular files and directories.

Peter Cordes's comment, which uses one `find` command, prevents double lookups of directory entries.  The more files there are, the more substantial this improvement is.  It still has the overhead of creating child `chmod` processes, which is why it is quite a bit slower than the `chmod`-only solution.

Between Fanatique's command and harrymc's updated command, `find` piped into `xargs` (`find | xargs`) was faster because the stream of results is processed asynchronously.  Instead of `find` pausing its find behavior for `-exec`, the found results are sent to `xargs` for concurrent processing.

(The null byte delimiter (`find -print0 | xargs -0`) did not seem to affect running time.)

harrymc's original command was too slow because of the overhead of a new `chmod` command for every single file and folder, each executed in sequence.

---

In the test setup, there were 1000002 regular files contained within 1001 directories:

```
root@demo:~# echo {0..999} | xargs mkdir -p
root@demo:~# find -type d -exec bash -c "cd {}; echo {0..999} | xargs touch" \;
root@demo:~# find | wc -l
1001003
root@demo:~# find -type d | wc -l
1001
root@demo:~# find -type f | wc -l
1000002
```

I set all of the files and folders to have `777` permissions, like the initial conditions of the question.

Then, I benchmarked the commands ten times, each time restoring the permissions to `777` with `chmod -R 0777 "$(pwd)"` before running the test.

With `OUTPUT` representing a file that contains the output of each benchmark command, I calculated the average time using:

```
bc <<< "scale=3; ($(grep real OUTPUT | grep -Po '(?<=m).*(?=s)' | xargs | sed 's/ /+/g'))/10"
```

#### Results of the benchmark of Deltik's answer

```
root@demo:~# for i in {0..9} ; do chmod -R 0777 "$(pwd)" ; time { find "$(pwd)" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -P4 chmod 755 & find "$(pwd)" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P4 chmod 644 & wait ; } ; done
[1] 9791
[2] 9793
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m7.634s
user    0m2.536s
sys     0m23.384s
[1] 9906
[2] 9908
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m7.443s
user    0m2.636s
sys     0m23.106s
[1] 10021
[2] 10023
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m8.005s
user    0m2.672s
sys     0m24.557s
[1] 10136
[2] 10138
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m7.480s
user    0m2.541s
sys     0m23.699s
[1] 10251
[2] 10253
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m7.397s
user    0m2.558s
sys     0m23.583s
[1] 10366
[2] 10368
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m7.482s
user    0m2.601s
sys     0m23.728s
[1] 10481
[2] 10483
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m7.679s
user    0m2.749s
sys     0m23.395s
[1] 10596
[2] 10598
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m7.243s
user    0m2.583s
sys     0m23.400s
[1] 10729
[2] 10731
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m7.320s
user    0m2.640s
sys     0m23.403s
[1] 10844
[2] 10847
[1]-  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type d | xargs -P4 chmod 755
[2]+  Done                    find "$(pwd)" -type f | xargs -P4 chmod 644

real    0m7.121s
user    0m2.490s
sys     0m22.943s
```

Average time: 7.480 seconds

#### Results of the benchmark of sitaram's answer

```
root@demo:~# for i in {0..9} ; do chmod -R 0777 "$(pwd)" ; time chmod -R a=,u+rwX,go+rX "$(pwd)" ; done

real    0m12.860s
user    0m0.940s
sys     0m11.725s

real    0m13.059s
user    0m0.896s
sys     0m11.937s

real    0m12.819s
user    0m0.945s
sys     0m11.706s

real    0m13.078s
user    0m0.855s
sys     0m12.000s

real    0m12.653s
user    0m0.856s
sys     0m11.667s

real    0m12.787s
user    0m0.820s
sys     0m11.834s

real    0m12.651s
user    0m0.916s
sys     0m11.578s

real    0m13.098s
user    0m0.939s
sys     0m12.004s

real    0m13.586s
user    0m1.024s
sys     0m12.372s

real    0m13.026s
user    0m0.976s
sys     0m11.910s
```

Average time: 12.962 seconds

#### Results of the benchmark of Peter Cordes's comment

```
root@demo:~# for i in {0..9} ; do chmod -R 0777 "$(pwd)" ; time find "$(pwd)" \( -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + \) -o \( -type f -exec chmod 644 {} + \) ; done

real    0m14.096s
user    0m1.455s
sys     0m12.456s

real    0m14.492s
user    0m1.398s
sys     0m12.897s

real    0m14.309s
user    0m1.518s
sys     0m12.576s

real    0m14.451s
user    0m1.477s
sys     0m12.776s

real    0m15.101s
user    0m1.554s
sys     0m13.378s

real    0m14.223s
user    0m1.470s
sys     0m12.560s

real    0m14.266s
user    0m1.459s
sys     0m12.609s

real    0m14.357s
user    0m1.415s
sys     0m12.733s

real    0m14.393s
user    0m1.404s
sys     0m12.830s

real    0m14.448s
user    0m1.492s
sys     0m12.717s
```

Average time: 14.414 seconds

#### Results of the benchmark of Fanatique's answer

```
root@demo:~# for i in {0..9} ; do chmod -R 0777 "$(pwd)" ; time { find "$(pwd)" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755 ; find "$(pwd)" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644 ; } ; done

real    0m14.561s
user    0m1.991s
sys     0m13.343s

real    0m14.521s
user    0m1.958s
sys     0m13.352s

real    0m14.696s
user    0m1.967s
sys     0m13.463s

real    0m14.562s
user    0m1.875s
sys     0m13.400s

real    0m14.609s
user    0m1.841s
sys     0m13.533s

real    0m14.892s
user    0m2.050s
sys     0m13.630s

real    0m14.291s
user    0m1.885s
sys     0m13.182s

real    0m14.843s
user    0m2.066s
sys     0m13.578s

real    0m14.219s
user    0m1.837s
sys     0m13.145s

real    0m14.503s
user    0m1.803s
sys     0m13.419s
```

Average time: 14.570 seconds

#### Results of the benchmark of harrymc's updated answer

```
root@demo:~# for i in {0..9} ; do chmod -R 0777 "$(pwd)" ; time { find "$(pwd)" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + ; find "$(pwd)" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} + ; } ; done

real    0m14.975s
user    0m1.728s
sys     0m13.050s

real    0m14.710s
user    0m1.586s
sys     0m12.979s

real    0m14.644s
user    0m1.641s
sys     0m12.872s

real    0m14.927s
user    0m1.706s
sys     0m13.036s

real    0m14.867s
user    0m1.597s
sys     0m13.086s

real    0m15.119s
user    0m1.666s
sys     0m13.259s

real    0m14.878s
user    0m1.590s
sys     0m13.098s

real    0m14.852s
user    0m1.681s
sys     0m13.045s

real    0m14.380s
user    0m1.603s
sys     0m12.663s

real    0m14.558s
user    0m1.514s
sys     0m12.899s
```

Average time: 14.791 seconds

#### Results of the benchmark of harrymc's original answer

*Due to how slow this command was, I only ran the benchmark once.*

```
root@demo:~# for i in {0..0} ; do chmod -R 0777 "$(pwd)" ; time { find "$(pwd)" -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; ; find "$(pwd)" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; ; } ; done
 
real    17m41.926s
user    12m26.896s
sys     4m58.332s
```

Time taken: 1061.926 seconds

Comment: +1 : Good and comprehensive analysis.

Comment: Why `"$(pwd)"`? Is there any difference with simply putting `.`?

Comment: @JoL: I used `"$(pwd)"` to simulate longer paths in the argument list. Performance would be a bit better with `.` because more paths could fit in before exceeding the maximum argument length.

Comment: "$PWD" is a simpler way to write that; you don't need to invoke a command and capture its output because the shell already maintains a variable with that value.

Comment: `find | xargs` is like `find -exec {} +` (GNU extension) not `find -exec {} \;` (POSIX standard, but only passes one filename per fork+exec.  Starting a whole dynamically-linked process for every `chmod` system call is obviously inefficient.)  Your *this way was somehow faster* doesn't have to be so vague; the way these things work is fully documented and (I thought) well known.  [The `xargs(1)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) is pretty clear about how it builds up args into long commands; that's one of the main reasons it exists.  See the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: All of the `find` answers traverse the tree twice because they don't bother to use find's and/or capabilities.  `find \( -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + \) -o \( -type f -exec chmod 644 + \)` should work.  Although I haven't tried it to make sure the two `-exec` actions accumulate args separately when `find` encounters alternating files and directories.  And BTW, if you have many files per directory, `-execdir {} +` might be good to allow more names on one command line and avoid making the kernel traverse as many directory components in each `chmod` system call.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Generally good points. (Re: [1](https://bit.ly/2GkCUQC)) I made `"$(pwd)"` a habit back when I worked with scripts that changed `$PWD` for some reason. Of course, `"$PWD"` would be just fine for the tests. (Re: [2](https://bit.ly/2M4cZR8)) @harrymc changed to `find -exec {} +`, which is what I benchmarked, but `find | xargs` was still faster, and I have now addressed why in [revision 6 of my answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1462081/revisions). (Re: [3](https://bit.ly/2Gm2gOf)) I added your suggested command to the benchmarks.

Comment: Nice update, that's a lot more clear on what's being compared to what.  Now I see you're saying xargs might be batching somewhat better than `find`, or maybe find goes through `/bin/sh`?  Might be interesting to `strace -f -eexecve` on `find -exec` and on `find | strace ... xargs` to see how many fork+execve invocations we get.   If `xargs` is building longer command lines, maybe it knows that in practice modern Linux allows extremely long command lines (like megabytes), while maybe `find` is more conservative.  And thanks for testing my one-find idea :)

Comment: @PeterCordes: [Both `find -exec` and `find | xargs` split the same number of times](https://web.archive.org/web/20190721154255if_/https://pastebin.com/raw/fkc7sFwm).  I think `find | xargs` is a bit faster because the two commands work in parallel.  With `find -exec`, the file search pauses while the `-exec` command runs.  (That's what I understood from the `strace` outputs, which were too big to paste.)

Comment: Oh yes, parallelism would do it.  I even thought of that at one point but forgot to comment about it >.<.  You can run both `find|xargs` commands in parallel, too.  Use `&` instead `;` to separate them.  They probably don't spend much of their time holding locks on directory entries the other process needs to traverse so they should overlap nicely.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Brilliant idea!  Using Bash jobs (`&`) and `xargs -P4` sped things up by about 42.667%.  [Revision 9 of my answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1462081/revisions) adds the benchmarks for the resulting parallel `chmod` command.

Comment: I'm curious about the type of disk used in your benchmarks. Parallelizing disk accesses works great on SSDs but you can't really effectively parallelize writes on a spinning disk that well.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz: The benchmarks in the answer were run on a Samsung MZVPV512HDGL NVMe SSD with about 155GB of 512GB used or untrimmed. The parallel command is still fastest on spinning disks. I don't have any machines with just one HDD at the moment. I hacked together a benchmark script that you can use to reproduce the tests yourself. Scripts: [benchmark script](https://pastebin.com/raw/mXUV1A82), [output file parser](https://pastebin.com/raw/F6rYmQ68). Results: [HDD ZFS RAID-1 results](https://pastebin.com/raw/TgDRpRne), [HDD hardware RAID-5 results](https://pastebin.com/raw/NTtBCErR)

Comment: Parallism alone doesn't cut it.  You also have to hit the disk cache (so the first pass does not have to reread the whole thing) and the output period overlaps the two.   Also delayed writing may be a tunable parameter.

Comment: I suspect the reason your solution is faster than harrymc's second one is that in yours the two `find`s will run in parallel. This allows the second one to read the directory information that the first one has pulled into the fs cache.

Comment: You should consider adding -print0 to your solution, as it will allow handling of files/directories with whitespace in the names.

Comment: You know, you should combine the parallelism with my solution and see if it makes a difference.  So basically `find ${pwd} | xargs -P4 chmod a=,u+rwX,go+rX`

Comment: @sitaram: The performance is [almost exactly the same](https://pastebin.com/raw/Vm5asDgA).

Comment: @Deltik -- good to know.  That is what I was guessing also.  In terms of syscalls, your method would be 2D+F stat calls from the find commands, and D+F chmod calls from the chmod, disregarding forks.  My method would be D+F stat and D+F chmod.  I suspect you'll only see a difference if the number of directories (D) is approaching that of the number of files (F), or is larger, like say if you have thousands of empty directories.

Answer (score 3):

If the directories are way too large and contain way too many files, the original way that @harrymc has shown you will fail.

If you have too many files, you'll need to pipe `find` to `xargs` with `chmod`:

```
find /base/dir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755 
find /base/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

Comment: Your way is actually faster than [@harrymc's](https://superuser.com/a/1462065/83694), but the reason is not correct. The reason is that the invocations of `chmod` are reduced because `xargs` automatically stacks arguments without exceeding the shell limit.  @harrymc's way runs `chmod` on every single file and directory.

Comment: I was thinking about a recursive shell doing `test -d`and `test -f` and then `chmod`accordingly. I just didn't think about `find`. Thanks @Fanatique and @harrymc

Comment: @mszmurlo: [I benchmarked the two answers](https://superuser.com/a/1462081/83694) and found that [@Fanatique's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1462066/83694) is faster.

Comment: Why do you claim harrymc's answer would fail with too many files? I think that's an incorrect claim.